# Material Angular change color of placeholder

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6, Material-UI, and I am trying to change the color of the placeholder/input in the select.

```
.mat-select-placeholder {
    color: white !important;
   background-color: red;
}
```

*red background is set for testing.*

I am seeing that the background of it changed to `red`, but the text is still dark-gray.

Is there a reason it is not changing?

Comment: Have u cleared ur Cache and tried?

Answer (score 1):

try using using ::ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-placeholder {
    color: white !important;
   background-color: red;
}
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> You an use `/deep/` to overwrite.

```
/deep/ .mat-select-placeholder {
   color: white !important;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Note : These options will be removed in future.

Walk through this link to understand how it works - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/